# img.save(imgstore, "GIF") or img.save(imgstore, "JPEG")

Tags: python, django, image, python-imaging-library

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():            
            u_file = request.FILES['docfile']            
            filename = u_file.name
            img = Image.open(u_file)
            imgstore = StringIO.StringIO("")
            img.save(imgstore, "GIF")
```

I am uploading an image file that gets converted into text. However I can only do it for GIF files. Or if I type "JPEG" instead of GIF, I can only save JPEG files. How can I save both JPEG and GIF using the img.save(imgstore, "GIF, JPEG") option. Thanks

Comment: maybe you have to get first the extension of image then you can do if and else statement after that save

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find the type of file that you have got using libmagic.
and then decide from there.
https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic

Comment: Im using PIL library. Sorry Im new to Django and python

Comment: And no I cannot use any other applications. As this will be tried on a different computer and they would not have the python magic thing. Anyone know a way I can type in one line that saves both JPEG and GIF using img.save

Comment: Does it raise an error when you do it the wrong way just check for the error and do accordingly , you could also use @catherine's way check for extension except its possible in few situations there may not be a   n extension

Comment: Yeap, I got it working with checking the extensions. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
if form.is_valid():            
    u_file = request.FILES['docfile']            

    extension = u_file.split(".").lower()[-1]

    filename = u_file.name
    img = Image.open(u_file)
    imgstore = StringIO.StringIO("")

    if extension == "gif"
        img.save(imgstore, "GIF")
    else:
        img.save(imgstore, "JPEG")
```

Comment: this is just an idea. Find better approach